# Tensorflow/ffjs: Embedding Layer Weights are NaN after training with model.fit() method

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new in tensorflow (tfjs) programming and I would like to train embeddings for tasks and related actions. The idea is to have 2 embedding layers (one for the tasks and one for the according actions). What I am interested in, is to get the trained weights of the two embedding layers. However, after executing the model.fit(...) method, all weights of the embedding layers are **NaN**. I have no idea, what I am doing wrong.

With the following code snippet, I create the appropriate tensorflow network:

```
function createNetwork(samples, embeddingDimSize, taskIndexesLength, actionIndexesLength) {
const actionInput = tf.input({name: 'actionInput', shape: [1]})
const actionEmbedding = tf.layers.embedding({name: 'actionEmbedding', inputDim: actionIndexesLength, outputDim: embeddingDimSize}).apply(actionInput)

const taskInput = tf.input({name: 'taskInput', shape: [1]})
const taskEmbedding = tf.layers.embedding({name: 'taskEmbedding', inputDim: taskIndexesLength, outputDim: embeddingDimSize}).apply(taskInput)

const dotLayer = tf.layers.dot({normalize: true, axes: 2}).apply([taskEmbedding, actionEmbedding])

const reshapeLayer = tf.layers.reshape({targetShape: [1]}).apply(dotLayer)

const output = tf.layers.dense({name: "output", activation: "sigmoid", units: 1}).apply(reshapeLayer)
const model = tf.model({name: "myEmbeddings", inputs: [taskInput, actionInput], outputs: output})
model.compile({optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.0001), loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy']})
return model}
```

Hence, the topology of the network is sequentielly connected as follows:

- 2 Input layers with a single input either for task value or an action value
- 2 embedding layers connected with a dot product layer
- the dot product layer
- a reshape layer
- a dense layer for a binary output

I generate training examples for the input layer 1 and input layer 2 and adequately an output with the according labels (either 0 or 1)

then I try to fit the model with the training data by

```
await model.fit([x1, x2], y, { epochs: epochs, batchSize: 50 }
```

After that I request the weights of the embedding layers by:

```
model.getLayer('taskEmbedding').getWeights()[0].print()
model.getLayer('actionEmbedding').getWeights()[0].print()
```

I get no errors when executing everything.
Any ideas, what is going wrong with my code and what I have to change?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: After some investigation, I found now the bug in my code. The word embedding dimension index has to match the embedding layer index length. In my case I started the word vocabulary index at 1 instead of at 0. Therefore, I had to add +1 to the **inputDim** variable of the embedding layer definition. The alternative is to start your word vocabulary index at 0, then you must not add +1 to the inputDim variable. The example code in the following is required, if your word vocabulary index starts from 1. Word vocabulary means in that context that your words are indexed in order to make them uniquely processable by the network:

```
const actionEmbedding = tf.layers.embedding({name: 'actionEmbedding', inputDim: actionIndexesLength + 1, outputDim: embeddingDimSize}).apply(actionInput)
```

and

```
const taskEmbedding = tf.layers.embedding({name: 'taskEmbedding', inputDim: taskIndexesLength + 1, outputDim: embeddingDimSize}).apply(taskInput)
```